# Express passing parameters to template depending on the environment

Tags: node.js, templates, express, render, ejs

I am using Express and EJS templates. In production environment I am calling some middleware's and passing result to the template. req.body is returned from appRenderer middleware and req.chunk from webpackUtils middleware. Everything works fine but in development environment I am not using any of the middleware and I don't need too pass any parameters.

```
...
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  const appRenderer = require('./appRenderer').default
  app.use(appRenderer)

  const webpackUtils = require('./webpackUtils').default
  app.use(webpackUtils)
}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {app: req.body, webpack: req.chunk})
})
```

I tried something like this but it is not working.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
    res.render('index', {app: req.body, webpack: req.chunk})
  } else {
   res.render('index')
  }
})
```

How would I send parameters depending on environment? Is this even a problem, since everything is working and I can choose to render params that I passed or not in EJS template. I just don't like the idea that I am passing something that is not used?

Comment: The code is looks like ok. I think that `process.env.NODE_ENV` is equal to `production` on development environment. You can check it by `console.log`, heh. Another way to pass vars to render is set `res.locals`. You can check it too.

Comment: Thanks Aikon. process.env.NODE_ENV is equal to development on development environment since I designate it like that in package.json when calling the script. The whole 'if statement' inside express routes doesn’t function so I was wondering if I can write it any different. I will check res.local and if that does anything for me.